# You attempted to set the key `port` with the value `8883` on an object that is meant to be immutable and has been frozen

Tags: javascript, react-native, mqtt

Как исправить данную ошибку.

> You attempted to set the key `port` with the value `8883` on an object that is meant to be immutable and has been frozen

Получаю ее после того как пытаюсь повторно создать клиента для MQTT подключения. Что использую:  react-native,  а для mqtt подключения данную библиотеку [sp-react-native-mqtt](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sp-react-native-mqtt). Отлаживаю пока только на андроид устройстве.

Работает это так:

1. Открываю экран => запрос к REST API
2. Получаю конфигурацию => создаю MQTT клиента
3. Подключаю MQTT клиента
4. Обмен сообщениями РАБОТАЕТ
5. Нажимаю на кнопку назад в хедере => Обрабатывается отключение/удаление MQTT клиента
6. Переключаюсь на другой экран, где должен подключиться снова MQTT клиент
7. отправка (publish) => выдает эту ошибку

Насколько я понимаю, что существует некая сущность с ключом `port`, которая не может быть перезаписана при инициализации нового клиента.
Где она находится и как ее обработать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вопрос решен.
Первое - я отказался от использования `sp-react-native-mqtt` и написал собственную реализацию для [`paho js`](https://www.eclipse.org/paho/index.php?page=clients/js/index.php) mqtt клиента

Второе - использовал возможности [`useEffect`](https://ru.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html)-хука. Хук включает в себя возможность использования следующую конструкцию

```js
useEffect(() => {
    function do_smth() {
    }

    return () => {
      // здесь можно очистить все хандлеры в том числе и относящиеся к mqtt клиенту
    };
  });
```

Для сброса клинта mqtt или просто вызвать `unsubscribe` для определенных топиков и т.д. при переключении между экранами